# Who is the most recent Everton signing that previously played for Liverpool at any point in their career?

Tags: football, history, transfer

For example Kevin Sheedy played for Liverpool between 1978 and 1982 and then signed for Everton in 1982. Peter Beardsley played for Liverpool between 1987 and 1991 and then signed for Everton in 1991.

I'm wondering if there have been more recent signings.

Also, is there a complete list of all players who played for Liverpool and then Everton and vice/versa?

Comment: Do loan signings count?

Comment: Yes, let's include those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since loan signings count, the most recent player to do this was [Conor Coady](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conor_Coady), who spent the 2022-23 season on loan at Everton from Wolves, having previously come through the youth ranks at Liverpool.

In terms of permanent signings, Andy Lonergan spent a season at Liverpool in 2019-20 without playing any games, and then signed for Everton in 2021 (where he has, again, played zero games). The most recent player I can find to have signed permanently for Everton, having previously signed *and played for* Liverpool, was Don Hutchison, who played for Liverpool between 1990 and 1994, and Everton between 1998 and 2000.

I used [this](https://www.90min.com/posts/every-footballer-liverpool-everton) article to find this information, but it only lists the seven players that have done this during the Premier League era. [This other article](https://www.101greatgoals.com/news/all-of-the-stars-to-have-played-for-both-liverpool-and-everton-in-the-premier-league/) *claims* to be a complete list, but doesn't include any of the three players I mentioned above, so it's clearly not. If a complete list does exist, I've been unable to find it.